# Delete files from folder on startup

Tags: 18.04, scripts, startup, bashrc

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory/*
```

That would be the code. But where should i put it?
On rc.local, .bashrc or System > Preferences > Start-up applications?

Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

**System > Preferences > Start-up applications** would work only during log in to your desktop and *not* during boot.

It's better to set it as *cron* task: run `crontab -e` to assign new cron task. Add following line, assuming `/path/to/directory/*` is yours.

```
@reboot rm -rf /path/to/directory/*
```

`@reboot` is executed on startup.